# Change of fractional numbers from one base to another

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Suppose $x=0.a_1a_2\cdots a_n a_{n+1} \cdots$ is a nonterminating fraction in base $b>1.$We want to find the first n digits in base 10  accurately.Could somebody kindly tell how we can do it.I would be highly obliged for any responces\hints\suggestions

Comment: You are going to need to calculate each of the following terms to $r$ decimal places, base $(10)$, where determination of $r$ is pending.  $b^{-1} + b^{-2} + \cdots + b^{-k}.$  Here, the number of terms $k$ is also pending.  Assuming that you round to $r$ decimal places, the max error on each term is $(.5)10^{-r}.$  Assuming that you compute $k$ terms, your total error on these $k$ terms must be $\leq k \times (.5)10^{-r}.$  Further, since you are truncating the series after $k$ terms, you have to consider the max value (i.e. addt'l error) of the omitted trailing terms.  ...see next comment.

Comment: $(b-1) ~[ ~ b^{-(k+1)} + b^{-(k+2)} + b^{-(k+3)} + \cdots ~] \leq b^{-k}.$  So, you want $b^{-k} + (k \times (.5)10^{-r})$ to be less than $5 \times (10)^{-(n+1)}$ so that the result, rounded to $n$ decimal places is accurate.

Answer (score 1):

If we see a fraction can be represented in base 10 as $\frac{a_1}{10}+\frac{a_2}{10}+\frac{a_3}{100}....+\frac{a_n}{10^n}$ . Similarly in any base $r$ , a fraction can be represented as $\frac{a_1}{r}+\frac{a_2}{r^2}+\frac{a_3}{r^3}+\ldots+\frac{a_n}{r^n}$.

Let $F$ =  $\frac{a_1}{r}+\frac{a_2}{r^2}+\frac{a_3}{r^3}+\ldots+\frac{a_n}{r^n}$.

We have to find $a_1,a_2,\ldots$

Multiplying by $r$ on both sides we get

$rF$ =   $\frac{a_1}{1}+\frac{a_2}{r}+\frac{a_3}{r^2}+\ldots+\frac{a_n}{r^{n-1}}$.

We can see here that $a_1$ is the integer part of $rF$

And the rest of the terms are the fractional part. If we denote those terms by $F_1$ , then

$F_1$ =  $\frac{a_2}{r}+\frac{a_3}{r^2}+\frac{a_4}{r^3}+\ldots+\frac{a_n}{r^{n-1}}$.

By doing the process of multiplication again and again , we can find the digits in the required base .

Eg . Express $\frac{13}{16}$ of base $10$ in base $6$.

Ans) $\frac{13}{16} \times 6 = 4 + \frac{7}{8}$

$\frac{7}{8} \times 6 =  5 + \frac{1}{4}$

$\frac{1}{4} \times 6 = 1 + \frac{1}{2}$

$\frac{1}{2} \times 6 = 3 + \frac{0}{0}$

Now as the remainder is $0$ we have got our final answer.

So , $\frac{13}{16}$ in base $6$ is $0.4513$.

Comment: This is the reverse of what the OP is asking for. They want to convert *from* a non-decimal base to decimal.

Comment: Yes it is the reverse of what I am asking but neverthless useful and neat explanation for the problem assumed

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you know how to write a fraction $A/B$ in decimal form, i.e. $A/B=(0.d_1d_2...)_{10}$. Then, given that $x=(0.a_1a_2...)_b=\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i/b^i,$ just write each successive term in decimal form and add them until you have enough precision. How many terms do you need to add up? ...

Let $k$ be the number of terms required to give the fraction correctly to $n$ decimal digits; i.e., we seek $k$ such that $$x-\sum_{i=1}^ka_i/b^i < 0.5\,10^{-n}$$ Note that
$$\begin{align}x - \sum_{i=1}^ka_i/b^i &=\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i/b^i - \sum_{i=1}^k a_i/b^i\\[1ex]
&= \sum_{i=k+1}^\infty a_i/b^i \\[1ex]
&\le\sum_{i=k+1}^\infty (b-1)/b^i \\[1ex]
&\le{b-1\over b^{k+1}}\sum_{i=0}^\infty 1/b^i \\[1ex]
&\le{b-1\over b^{k+1}}{1\over1-1/b} \\[1ex]
&\le 1/b^k
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we achieve the required precision if $1/b^k<0.5\,10^{-n} $, or $k>{n+1\over \log_{10}b}.$

**Example**

To find the first $4$ decimal digits of $x=\pi-3=(0.06636514...)_7,$ we note  ${4+1\over\log_{10} 7}=5.91...$, so the first $6$ of the base-$7$ digits will be sufficient:
$$\begin{align}(0.066365)_7=0/7+6/7^2+6/7^3+3/7^4+6/7^5+5/7^6=(0.14159...)_{10}
\end{align}$$